# Convert lb and oz to grams - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I have a column for weight in lb and oz together

For example we have data like this in the column:

```
8 lb 8.863 oz
6900 lb 7.495 oz
```

Can someone help me to convert the `lb+oz` together to grams?

```
Birthweight = Visit.WeightField -- (TableName.FieldName)
```

I new we need to multiply by 454 but it doesn't work.

Please help me in change the above Weightfield column in SQL line.

For example conversion of kgs to grams is as follows

```
  BirthWeight= ISnull(cast((cast(rtrim(replace(Visit.WeightField,'kg','')) as float) * 1000) as varchar(max)),'0')
```

Comment: The *real* problem here is that you have the **`varchar`** value `'8 lb 8.863 oz'`, not a column `Lbs` with the **`int`** value `8`, and another column `oz` with the `decimal` value `8.863`. You *really* need to fix your design. Then you can easily convert this

Comment: Also, why tag MySQL **and** SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

As I mention, fix the design, fix the problem.

```
--Sample table and data
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (LbOz varchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('8 lb 8.863 oz'),('6900 lb 7.495 oz'),
      ('12 lb'),('4.867 oz');
GO
--Add normalised data
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Lb int;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Oz decimal(5,3);
GO
--UPDATE values of normalised data
UPDATE YT
SET Lb = ISNULL(CONVERT(int,LEFT(YT.LbOz, CI.Lb - 2)),0),
    Oz = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),SUBSTRING(YT.LbOz,ISNULL((CI.LB+3),0),CI.Oz - ISNULL((CI.Lb+3),0))),0)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('lb',YT.LbOz),0),NULLIF(CHARINDEX('oz',YT.LbOz),0)))CI(Lb,Oz)
GO
--Convert to Grams
SELECT Lb, Oz,
       ((lb * 16) + oz) * 28.3495 AS g
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ef7f607e4444e1227216e71e634c84e)

***Warning***: This assumes some consistency to your data. If you have values like `'7lbs4oz'` this is **not** going to work. If that is the case, I suggest you add the columns (like above) and then fix your data manually. Then learn from the mistake and don't do it again.

Comment: Since my field in my query looks like this( Birth_Weight=Visit.WeightField) ... i need to manipulate that line.

Comment: Not sure what your point is there @SanthoshKumar . You have all you need above.

Comment: Instead of all this query here . Could you show me in one single line how to modify line using weightfield column for conversion of lb and oz together to grams.  Please look for the query i used to convert kgs to grams in my question .I need this one similar to that line

Comment: You can't add the new columns, update them, and then calculate grams in one query, @Santhoshkumar . If you don't understand the above, however, then you're lacking fundamental understandings of SQL, and need to spend time learning them.